# How to manage a views term filter at run-time?

Tags: 7, views

I have a D7 View for which i need to pass filters at runtime and cannot use exposed filters. 
I use

```
$filter = $view_search_works->get_item($display_id, 'filter', 'filter_name_tid');
$filter['value'] = VALUE;
$view_search_works->set_item($display_id, 'filter', 'filter_name_tid', $filter);
```

for the filter i have defined for a taxonomy term.

If i define the filter with the "Is one of" and select all the taxonomy listed terms,when i pass one of the listed value, it runs fine.

The (big) problem is that if i define a new term (and it can happen) and pass it to the view, the term is not recognized and the view does not work.

Is there a way to say "all the taxonomy terms" for the filter? If i don't select a term when i define the filter, i get "No valid values found on filter:name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to use a "Filter"? If you can use a "Contextual filter" instead, then this should work without you needing to specify which terms are allowed.

Another, much more complicated option, would be to implement [hook_entity_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7) and update the Views configuration on new terms.

Comment: Great, i used a contextual filter and worked ! Thanks very much.